# Orderby after Select at LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have LINQ query to get all PreQualCheck, then I need to order by PreQualChecks by descending and get the first one from the ordered collection

Here is how I try to write query:

```
var preQuals = _positionsRepository.GetAll()
                .Include(x => x.LoanApplication.PreQualificationChecks)
                .Where(x => x.Id == invoice.Position.Id)
                .Select(x => x.LoanApplication.PreQualificationChecks)
                .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But I get error at `.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Id)`, because it couldn't get Id

How I can fix this?

Comment: You can fix it by calling first `OrderBy` an then `Select`

Comment: But it will order by `Positions`

I need to order by `PreQualificationChecks`  @SomeBody

Comment: Does the PreQualificationChecks have a single Id property?

Comment: Yes, it has single id and FK to `LoanApplication` @Diederik

Comment: Are you sure PreQualificationChecks is not a collection? This code you show us should work.

Comment: PreQualificationChecks is collection that is related at LoanApplication @Diederik

Comment: Then do .SelectMany() instead of .Select(), that will flatten a collection of collections to one collection.

Comment: Could we have the error message? information on the type of `PreQualificationChecks`? And if it's a collection of X, inforamtion on that X especially the declaration of the ID property. Or a [mre]. with just the bare minimun class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var preQuals = _positionsRepository.GetAll()
                .Include(x => x.LoanApplication.PreQualificationChecks)
                .Where(x => x.Id == invoice.Position.Id)
                .Select(x => new {x.Id, PreQualificationChecks=x.LoanApplication.PreQualificationChecks})
                .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

then you can access preQuals like this:

```
preQuals.PreQualificationChecks
```